# Converting only specific items in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, encryption

I am trying to make a code where I convert a string of numbers into floats to them be converted into octal and ascii values. However, if the number can't be converted into an octal (aka a negative number) it should be printed as the negative float. Currently I can get things into ascii values but it still doesn't skip over the negative values.

```
characters = input("Input a string of numbers to be encrypted with spaces in between each value: ")
charcters = str(characters)

values = characters.split()
new_values = [float(i) for i in values]
print(new_values)

integers = list(map(int, new_values))

octal_values = list(map(oct, integers))
print(octal_values)
ascii_values = list(map(chr, octal_values))
print(ascii_values)
```

This is something I tried for separating the negative and positive floats (obviously doesn't work):

```
characters = input("Input a string of numbers to be encrypted with spaces in between each value: ")
charcters = str(characters)

values = characters.split()
new_values = [float(i) for i in values]
print(new_values)

integers = list(map(int, new_values))

for num in integers:
    if num < 0:
        print(end= " ")
    if num > 0:
        octal_values = list(map(oct, num))
        print(octal_values)
        ascii_values = list(map(chr, octal_values))
        print(ascii_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Several issues

1. You have misspelled "characters" on the second line.
2. I have changed the input to a constant string, to make the debugging less painful.
3. I have changed the variable names to be more indicative of what is contained.
4. I assume you didn't want to convert each digit into an octal number?

```
    numbers_separated_by_spaces = "345435 -345435 12 12.33 -99"
    
    numbers = numbers_separated_by_spaces.split()
    floats = [float(i) for i in numbers]
    print(floats)

    integers = [int(f) for f in floats]
    for integer in integers:
        if integer < 0:
            print(integer, end= " ")
        if integer > 0:
            octal_value = oct(integer)
            print(octal_value, end=" ")
            ascii_values = chr(integer)
            print(ascii_values, end=" ")
```

I think this is *almost* what you want. However, the conversion from octal to ascii, I couldn't quite understand what you were intending. You will need to modify my code for that.